# Questions about the X-UA-Compatible header

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, http-headers, browser

First:

http://www.google.com/chromeframe/about/

This page says that Google will no longer support Google Chrome Frame and it is deprecated, then should it be still used?

`Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"`

`<?php header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1'); ?>`

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>`

Second:

So I prefer setting my headers in the .htaccess file. So should I use this code to limit the `X-UA-Compatible` header to IE only or to leave it for all browsers?

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    BrowserMatch (MSIE|Trident) ie
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1" env=ie
</IfModule>
```

Also which kind of files should have that header?

Comment: Why close vote? Didn't even comment to say what's wrong with my question so I can improve it.

Comment: The close vote says “too broad”. I conside casting a different close vote: unclear what you are asking. Do you have a problem with retiring Chrome Frame (took place over a year ago), of with setting response headers, or what?

Comment: I was just asking should `chrome=1` still be used and should this header be used with IE only or all browsers? I don't know what was unclear in the question's body...

Comment: Should you use a tag that affects a plug-in that was deprecated a year ago? That’s really opinion-based, or depends on a particular situation (like an intranet using that plug-in for some odd reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment above, using `chrome=1` or not depends on you. I'd use this code in my.htaccess file, thou:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    BrowserMatch (MSIE|Trident) ie
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1" env=ie
</IfModule>
```